# Can CMOS Checksum error damage my computer

Tags: boot

At time of booting i saw the CMOS check sum error. if this is battery related & it is not replaced, can it damage my computer?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is **no**. However, if you do not replace the battery, some BIOS settings, as well as the firmware level storage of date and time will cease (but it shouldn't be too big of an issue, as most modern operating systems retrieve and sync their time with a time server). Eventually, the computer may also refuse to boot. At this point, try giving the computer at least a week of rest; many computers are still able to come back after that. Otherwise, it may be time to replace the battery or get a new computer.